# integral transforms: why do roots in frequency domain correspond to eigenvalues in time domain (and how does it help solve differential equations)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-transforms, big-picture, laplace-transform

In Wikipedia you can read about [integral transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform), esp. the Laplace transform which maps a differential equation in the time domain into a polynomial equation in the complex frequency domain:

> roots of the polynomial equations in the complex frequency domain correspond to eigenvalues in the time domain

Can anybody give a simple example and foremost give an intuition why this is so - and why does this help solving the differential equation? I don't see the big picture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Linear, homogeneous, constant-coefficient) differential equations are *already* polynomial equations. That is, let $D$ denote the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$. Then linear homogeneous constant-coefficient differential equations are nothing more than equations of the form $p(D) y = 0$, where $y$ is some function of $x$ and $p$ is some polynomial. Writing $p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x - r_i)^{e_i}$ where the roots $r_i$ are distinct, it follows that we can write the equation as

$$(D - r_1)^{e_1} (D - r_2)^{e_2} ... (D - r_n)^{e_n} y = 0.$$

The point here is that $D$ is a linear operator, and it generates a commutative algebra of differential operators. Now, from the above it follows that any solution to $(D - r_i)^{e_i} y = 0$ is a solution to the above, and it turns out that linear combinations of these give all solutions. (This is a general fact about linear operators on finite-dimensional vector spaces; see, for example, Axler's [Linear Algebra Done Right](http://linear.axler.net/).)

In the special case that $e_i = 1$ for all $i$ things are particularly simple: $(D - r_i) y = 0$ just means $Dy = r_i y$, or $y = c_i e^{r_i x}$ for some constant $c_i$. This gives $n$ linearly independent solutions, which is the correct number, hence the general solution has the form

$$y = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i e^{r_i x}.$$

If the multiplicities $e_i$ are higher then we must consider solutions to $(D - r_i)^{e_i} y = 0$. Let $w(x) = e^{-r_i x} y(x)$. Then $D w = e^{-r_i x} (D - r_i) y$, from which it follows that the above holds if and only if $D^{e_i} w = 0$. But this says precisely that $w$ is a polynomial of degree at most $e_i - 1$. Hence

$$y = c_i(x) e^{r_i x}$$

where $c_i(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $e_i - 1$. This gives $e_i$ linearly independent solutions, so again taking linear combinations we have found all of them.

**None of this requires that you know anything about integral transforms.** From the abstract point of view, integral transforms are just a convenient way to diagonalize $D$. The Laplace transform (more or less) takes $D$ to multiplication by $s$, hence turns $p(D)$ into $p(s)$ (the roots of which are the eigenvalues $r_i$ above), but this is just a more concrete way of realizing the abstract structure already evident in the problem: that the set of solutions to $p(D) y = 0$ is naturally acted on by $\mathbb{C}[D]$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give an example of how it works. I don't know why it works. The example is the simplest case from electric circuit theory, the discharge of a capacitor. You know the solution f(t) is just an exponential decay, truncated to the left at t=0. The Fourier Transform of f(t) is F(w) = 1/1+jw. Now observe:

F(w) + jw*F(w) = 1/1+jw  +  jw/1+jw  =  1

Now remember some properties of the Fourier transform: multiplication by jw in the frequency domain is equivalent to differentiation in the time domain. And the Fourier transform of a constant function in one domain is the delta function in the other domain. Using only these properties we can translate the above equation into words:

"A function plus its derivative is equal to the delta function".

This sentence is exactly the differential equation of a capactor which has a unit of charge dumped into it at t=0.